# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions after deleting Google Service Accounts

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

### Use Case

I am using Firebase JS SDK to access Cloud Firestore from Browser, so that I can push UI Logs and Errors into Firestore.

### Issue

It was all working fine until I, accidentally, *deleted most of the Service Accounts* in my Google Cloud Platform inside **APIs & Services → Credentials**.

Below is the sample Config that we use for a Firebase Web App:

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCztfcT6k6yXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "<some-domain>.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://<some-domain>.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "<some-domain>",
        storageBucket: "<some-domain>.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "877458876543",
        appId: "1:877458876543:web:9a9287dee234cd655ab7f2"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
```

I even tried reading [Firebase Service Accounts Overview](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts), but could not decide which Service Account to use for Firestore. Then, I tried adding different Service Accounts according to my Project ID and giving them Owner permissions to my Project, but it didn't work.

Full Error I am getting in Browser's Console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new Hr (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:48219)
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:378673
    at wr.<anonymous> (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:377569)
    at Wt (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:15221)
    at wr.S.dispatchEvent (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:16063)
    at Er.ua (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:45322)
    at nr.S.Fa (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:43229)
    at Ge (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:21453)
    at qe (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:20854)
    at Me.S.Ja (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:23264)
```

Actually, I want to cleanup my Service Accounts as there were many created by myself. Please guide in telling which Service Account to use and what suitable Permissions to give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore Security Rules depend on a service account named `service-PROJECT_NUMBER@firebase-rules.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with the role 
`roles/firebaserules.system`. You can use `gcloud` to restore this account:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID --member=serviceAccount:service-PROJECT_NUMBER@firebase-rules.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/firebaserules.system
```

To get the project number, see [Identifying projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects).

Comment: Strange behaviour. When I was trying it through UI, it was showing me only **Firebase Rules Admin** but I could not find **Firebase Rules System**. But now, after I've added it through `gcloud` command, it is now showing it in UI too.

Comment: That's right, the `firebaserules.system` IAM role is hidden in the console by default. You must use gcloud to set the role, but after that, the role becomes visible in the console.